# Interface Base class instantiation via generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have an interface that for example's sake looks like this:

```
interface IFoo<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
{
  TEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

I then have an abstract base class that looks like this:

```
abstract class FooBase<TEnum> : IFoo<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable
{
  public TEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

I then inherit from the base class like so:

```
class MyFoo : FooBase<MyFoo.MyFooEnum>
{
  public enum MyFooEnum
  {
    Foo1,
    Foo2,
  }
}
```

How can I instantiate a `MyFoo` from a generic method with type parameter `FooBase`?

I'm pretty much looking for something like this:

```
static class FooMethods
{
  public static TFooClass GetFoo<TFooClass>() where TFooClass : FooBase, new()
  {
    TFooClass fooclass = new TFooClass();
    return fooclass;
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that it wants type parameters for `FooBase`, but in reality I don't really care what the parameters are since my `MyFoo` has those type parameters already.

Comment: [Abstract factory pattern to the rescue!](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern)

Comment: @Liam I might just be tired but I'm not quite seeing how I'd implement that.

Comment: and you don't want to make the method signature like this `public static TFooClass GetFoo<TFooClass, TEnum>()`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I was hoping just specifying the derived class would be enough.

Comment: If the only thing `FooBase` exposes is that enum property, and you don't care what the enum type is in that method, why do you need to enforce that `TFooClass : FooBase`?

Comment: In reality my `FooBase` has a bunch of properties specified in the Interface as well, all of which I need access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit your generic class from a common base:

```
abstract class FooBase {
}

abstract class FooBase<TEnum> : FooBase, IFoo<TEnum>
where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable {
   public TEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}

public static TFooClass GetFoo<TFooClass>()
where TFooClass : FooBase, new() {
   TFooClass fooclass = new TFooClass();
   return fooclass;
}
```

But you won't be able to access the `MyEnum` property with a generic constraint of `FooBase`. (And how could you, without having specified the type?)

That, or you need to add another type parameter to `GetFoo`:

```
abstract class FooBase<TEnum> : IFoo<TEnum>
where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable {
   public TEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}

public static TFooClass GetFoo<TFooClass, TEnum>()
where TFooClass : FooBase<TEnum>, new()
where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable {
   TFooClass fooclass = new TFooClass();
   return fooclass;
}
```

UPDATE: Another thing I could point out is that if you find that you need to call this `GetFoo` method a lot, then if you put it in an instance class instead of a static class, you can push one or both of the type arguments up into the class instead of always specifying it in the method. This can make some code a little less verbose, but really only if you call this method a lot. Ex:

```
public sealed FooFactory<TEnum>
where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable {
   public static TFooClass GetFoo<TFooClass>()
   where TFooClass : FooBase<TEnum>, new() {
      TFooClass fooclass = new TFooClass();
      return fooclass;
   }
}

...

var factory = new FooFactory<SomeEnum>();
var foo1 = factory.GetFoo<SomeFooClass1>();
var foo2 = factory.GetFoo<SomeFooClass2>();

// or the other way:

var factory = new FooFactory<SomeFooClass>();
var foo1 = factory.GetFoo<SomeEnum1>();
var foo2 = factory.GetFoo<SomeEnum2>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do next:

```
abstract class FooBase
{
}

abstract class FooBase<TEnum> : FooBase, IFoo<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable
{
  public TEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}

static class FooMethods
{
  public static TFooClass GetFoo<TFooClass>() where TFooClass : FooBase, new()
  {
    TFooClass fooclass = new TFooClass();
    return fooclass;
  }
}
```

Comment: Then I don't have access to anything in `FooBase<TEnum>` which I absolutely need.