# Generics: why can't the compiler infer the type parameter contraints?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-inference

This question stems off one I asked yesterday: [Interface Base class instantiation via generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285222/interface-base-class-instantiation-via-generic-method)

For completeness sake I will reuse the examples I used in that question.

If I have an interface like so:

```
interface IFoo<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
{
  TEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a base class, like so:

```
abstract class FooBase<TEnum> : IFoo<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable
{
  public TEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

I then inherit from the base class, like so:

```
class MyFoo : FooBase<MyFoo.MyFooEnum>
{
  public enum MyFooEnum
  {
    Foo1,
    Foo2,
  }
}
```

I then have a generic method, that has to look like this:

```
static class FooMethods
{
  public static TFooClass GetFoo<TFooClass, TEnum>() 
    where TFooClass : FooBase<TEnum>, new()
    where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable //why is this necessary?
  {
    TFooClass fooclass = new TFooClass();
    return fooclass;
  }
}
```

My question is why I need to specify what type my base class will take, when the base class specifies that itself? If my derived class inherits from the base class, then the compiler should be able to infer the type parameter constraints of the base class purely by looking at what the base class requires?

Comment: You mean infer the generic type parameter *constraints*?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, that's what I meant. Edited question for clarity.

Comment: Base class **does not** specifies the type, however the class `MyFoo` is inherited from `FooBase` with the type `MyFooEnum`